# How to remove last two element from each sublists in dict

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

Is it possible to remove all elements expect first one from each sublists which is act as a value in dict without using any loop

let d =

```
 [
    { "x":1640995200000, "y": [2365,2567.300049,2305,2386.600098] },
    { "x":1643673600000, "y": [2408,2456.399902,2243,2359.550049] },
    { "x":1646092800000, "y": [2359.550049,2688,2180,2634.750000] }
]
```

output =

```
 [
    { "x":1640995200000, "y": 2365 },
    { "x":1643673600000, "y": 2408 },
    { "x":1646092800000, "y": 2359.550049 }
]
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use a loop? You should use the most appropriate technique available. If a loop of some kind is most appropriate then that's what you should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an explicit loop of some kind will make it clearer to the reader / maintainer what you're trying to do. However, if you really want to obfuscate the process then you could do this:

```
d = [
    { "x":1640995200000, "y": [2365,2567.300049,2305,2386.600098] },
    { "x":1643673600000, "y": [2408,2456.399902,2243,2359.550049] },
    { "x":1646092800000, "y": [2359.550049,2688,2180,2634.750000] }
]

output = list(map(lambda _d: {'x': _d['x'], 'y': _d['y'][0]}, d))

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'x': 1640995200000, 'y': 2365}, {'x': 1643673600000, 'y': 2408}, {'x': 1646092800000, 'y': 2359.550049}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the lists have at least one element in each.

```
d = [{"x":item["x"], "y": item["y"][0]} for item in d]
```

More about list comprehension could be found here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: btw second element should be in single element format.. not as a list

Comment: @UjjalModak To do that. Use index, not slice. See my updated answer

Comment: Working.. but can we do the same without using any loop

Comment: @UjjalModak, with limited number of elements, you can. But not sure maximum length of the list `d`  in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['y'] = df['y'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df.to_dict('records')
```